# Why are RGB channels swapped in Caffe's Examples?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

When I look at `Caffe`'s examples, they seem to always swap channels.
What is the reason behind it ?
Below is an exmaple taken from Caffe classification [example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb):

```
transformer.set_transpose('data', (2,0,1))  # move image channels to outermost dimension
transformer.set_mean('data', mu)            # subtract the dataset-mean value in each channel
transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255)      # rescale from [0, 1] to [0, 255]
transformer.set_channel_swap('data', (2,1,0))  # swap channels from RGB to BGR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very annoying feature caffe got from opencv. It appears as if opencv reads color images, by default, in BGR format.